# UIImage -> CGImageRef

Tags: cocoa-touch, image, uiimage, cgimageref

I'm building an Iphone app that needs to convert a UIImage to a CGImageRef. I have no idea how to do this and would love some help. I have no background in working with images... :)

Answer (score 110, accepted):

It is as simple as `image.CGImage` where `image` is a `UIImage` object.

Comment: Do note that the CGImage may not be exactly equivalent to the UIImage. In particular, watch out for `imageOrientation` being other than `UIImageOrientationUp`.

Comment: Be aware of `image` could also be created from `CIImage`

Answer (score 17):

```
CGImageRef cgImage = [someImage CGImage];
```

Comment: Unless the UIImage was initialized from a CIImage, in that case, CGImage will be nil.

Answer (score 3):

write folowing to get  CGImage from UIImage:
Suppose u have an UIImage object ex imageObject then,

```
CGImage imageRef = imageObject.CGImage
```