# iOS: Draw image multiple times in context

Tags: ios, graphics, core-graphics

I have some image, and i wish to draw it in my UIControl. But for increasing performance i need to draw in graphic context.

Now i can use something like that:

```
var imageRect1 = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)
var imageRect2 = CGRectMake(x2, y2, width, height)
...
CGContextDrawImage(ctx, imageRect1, image)
CGContextDrawImage(ctx, imageRect2, image)
...
```

But this solution means that we at least read `image` every time that call that context function. 
I search some solution that would work with some steps, like next one (feel free to correct me if I am wrong):

```
//read image into some bitmap or maybe some byte array
//paste it several times in different places (several times means ~500 times)
```

Maybe I have to copy pixel by pixel? Can someone give me some advice how to do it fast?

Comment: what do you want to archieve? If you want to draw a pattern/tiled image there a better ways using `[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:]` or `CGContextDrawTiledImage`. If you need direct control over where every image appears you could use `CGLayer`.

Comment: Imagine that i have something [like that](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NnPOu.png) And i need to insert 500 times image. So I try to find some way do not read image 500 times. Maybe read first pixel in my image bitmap array and assign it in 500 position in result bitmap array? I don't know which way i should use for gain some valuable performance, and how should i do it..

Comment: You could also use the `drawInRect` or the `drawAtPoint` method and then get an image from the current context.

Comment: @VitaliyLevytskyy: Out of curiosity, how did you eventually solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

**if** you have a single image to draw in a CALayer, the über most solution is *to set the image as the contents property of the backing CALayer* as described in [Technical Q&A QA1708](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1708/_index.html).

```
self.imageLayer.contents = (id)image.CGImage
```

**else if** your concern is caching using `CGImageRef` and `CGContextRef`, your question has already been answered here:

[UIImage -> CGImageRef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067307/uiimage-cgimageref)

**else if** you are drawing directly in a `UIView`, see @boeqqsh comment:

```
let image = UIImage.imageNamed("image")
let imageRect1 = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)
let imageRect2 = CGRectMake(x2, y2, width, height)

image.drawInRect(imageRect1)
image.drawInRect(imageRect2)
```